# Inserting into a table from view create witha link server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have created a view that includes a view from a linked server and I am inserting into a table. when I query the table it returns no data when the where statement is referencing data from the linkserver table. It does however pull all the data when not using the where statement.  why is this for I do not have much experience working with LinkedServers.

Here is code I used to build my view i am using to populate my table.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[weightsDashboard]
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[weightsYak]

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENQUERY([10.3.50.62\AGJET], 'SELECT * FROM [CheckWeigher]. 
 [dbo].[weightsSs]')
```

Then I ran this to create the dataset I want to report off of.

```
select * 
into Dataset_SaleSummary
from  [dbo].[weightsDashboard]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention a where clause. Care to share it?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] so we see exactly what you do. A description is always ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause Would be driver. Use ODBC instead of OLE DB.If you are trying to connect oracle database from sql server

Delete the linked server from SQL Server
Right click on the "Linked Servers" folder and select "New Linked Server..."
Linked Server: enter anything..this will be the name of your new linked server
Provider: Select "Oracle Provider for OLE DB"
Product Name: enter "Oracle" (without the double quotes)
Data Source: enter the alias from your TNSNAMES.ORA file. 
Provider String: leave it blank
Location: leave it blank
Catalog: leave it blank
Now go to the "Security" tab, and click the last radio button that says "Be made using this security context:" and enter the username & password for your connection.

I had exact same problem with an SQL 2014 getting data from SQL 2000 through OPENQUERY. Because ODBC compatibility problem, I had to keep generic OLE DB for ODBC driver. Moreover, the problem was only with SQL non-admin account. So finally, the solution I found was to add SET ROWCOUNT 0:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DWH_LINK, 'SET ROWCOUNT 0 SELECT * FROM TABLEA ')
```

It seems the rowcount might been change somewhere through the SQL procedure (or for this user session), so setting it to 0 force it to return "all rows".